# render hashmap data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hashmap

I'm retrieving hashmap data from an api into my react app. the data looks like this..

```
[
    [
        "d243dc7-6fe8-151b-4ca8-1be528f2b36",
        "[\"Jonny\",70]"
    ],
    [
        "8affa17-76d1-13e-6380-7cd2a3e3647",
        "[\"Lucy\",106,"pic3.jpg"]"
    ],
    [
        "841cb28-24c7-872-3c66-63253800c8d",
        "[\"Mike\",0]"
    ],
    [
        "6128e-182-cfb4-708b-c40a3ba2e6e",
        "[\"Elodie\",23,"me.jpg"]"
    ],
    [
        "e55ef4c-8d41-3be4-27d-aae53330584",
        "[\"Jacob\",9,"img-004.jpeg"]"
    ]
]
```

I need to render this data into a table.

Using map and with with data.slice(0, 1) I've managed to pull out the key (the long string), but I need help separating the name, number and optional image. I tried experimenting with various operators. I thought this would work

```
{data.slice(1, 2).toString().substring(2,data.slice(1, 2).length-2)}
```

but it just returns ["

I'm hoping there is a simpler way to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You presented the data in a strange format, but this works:

```js
const data = [
    [
        "d243dc7-6fe8-151b-4ca8-1be528f2b36",
        "[\"Jonny\",70]"
    ],
    [
        "8affa17-76d1-13e-6380-7cd2a3e3647",
        "[\"Lucy\",106,\"pic3.jpg\"]"
    ],
    [
        "841cb28-24c7-872-3c66-63253800c8d",
        "[\"Mike\",0]"
    ],
    [
        "6128e-182-cfb4-708b-c40a3ba2e6e",
        "[\"Elodie\",23,\"me.jpg\"]"
    ],
    [
        "e55ef4c-8d41-3be4-27d-aae53330584",
        "[\"Jacob\",9,\"img-004.jpeg\"]"
    ]
];

const data1 = JSON.parse(data.slice(1, 2)[0][1]);

console.log('name', data1[0]);
console.log('numb', data1[1]);
console.log('file', data1[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{data.slice(1, 2).toString().substring(2,data.slice(1, 2).length-2)}
                                       ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

1. In the string "["Jonny",70]" , you only want to skip the first character "[", so your first parameter of substring() should be index 1
2. you forgot to transfer data.slice(1, 2) to string, so it's still an array and its length would be 1

so your code should be revised to:

```
data.slice(1, 2).toString().substring(1, data.slice(1, 2).toString().length - 2)
```